# QGraphicsItem doesn't receive mouse hover events

Tags: c++, qt, events, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a class derived from `QGraphicsView`, which contains `QGraphicsItem`-derived elements.  I want these elements to change color whenever the mouse cursor hovers over them, so I implemented `hoverEnterEvent` (and `hoverLeaveEvent`):

```
void MyGraphicsItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent* event)
{
    update (boundingRect());
}
```

However, this event handler code is never executed.  I've explicitly enabled mouse tracking:

```
MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView(MainView *parent) :
    QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
    viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);
    ...
}
```

Still, no luck.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Fixed it.  I need to use `setAcceptHoverEvents(true)` in the constructor of my `QGraphicsItem`-derived class.

Comment: I had this same problem and removing the `mouseMoveEvent` implementation from my `QGraphicsView` was also necessary to fix it. Now that I have it working I could probably add `mouseMoveEvent` back in as long as I figure out a way for it to not eat up the `QEvent`.

Comment: @CoryKlein did you find the way to use both mouseMoveEvent and hover events?

Comment: @lena honestly I don't remember

Answer (score 7):

In my case, hover events wouldn't work if I overrode **mouseMoveEvent** in my implementation of the **QGraphicsView** class. I fixed this by adding a call to

```
QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
```

which propagated the event to the parent, which in turn sent it out to all the scene items.