# Using Hover Events

Tags: c++, qt, qt-events

I am having trouble capturing the hover enter and hover leave events in a `QGraphicsRectItem`.

I have subclassed this object, and reimplemented the hover enter and hover leave handlers... or at least I think I have. I also set accepts hover event to true in the constructor.

The event is never fired, however. Breakpoints inside the handlers are never hit.

Here is the class:

```
#include "qhgraphicsrectitem.h"

QhGraphicsRectItem::QhGraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem *parent) :
    QGraphicsRectItem(parent)
{
    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    setAcceptsHoverEvents(true);
}

void QhGraphicsRectItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) {
    oldBrush = brush();
    setBrush(QBrush(QColor((oldBrush.color().red() + (0.5 * (255-oldBrush.color().red()))),(oldBrush.color().green() + (0.5 * (255-oldBrush.color().green()))),(oldBrush.color().blue() + (0.5 * (255-oldBrush.color().blue()))))));
}

void QhGraphicsRectItem::hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) {
    setBrush(oldBrush);
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: The posted code looks good, except for "setAcceptsHoverEvents" which isn't a method of QGraphicsItem. Maybe that's something else you've done. Anyways, you might have to call `update()` after `setBrush`. Are you messing with the rect at all?

Comment: @Anthony I'm not changing the rect, no. I'm not handling these events with my QGraphicsView or QGraphicsScene either...

I tried update, nothing happened.

Comment: "setAcceptsHoverEvent" used to be in the class, they took it out it was depreciated, if you check their sources you'll see. Items don't get hover events because mousemove events dont happen by default when the mouse is up. To get those, override, or use QGraphicsView::setMouseTracking(true) to get the mouse move events to be sent down w/o buttons having to be pressed... i've personally had to update code from setAcceptsHoverEvents to setAcceptHoverEvents, seems like a silly thing to change but i guess it wasn't totally unambiguous so..

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940392/qgraphicsitem-doesnt-receive-mouse-hover-events .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mark your `hoverEnterEvent` and `hoverLeaveEvent` as virtual?  If you didn't, the events could be triggering but the `QGraphicsItem` is handling the event instead.

```cpp
class QhGraphicsRectItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
    ...
    virtual void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);
    virtual void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);
}
```

Comment: I have them defined as protected virtual void.

Comment: This is unnecessary. The proper advice for C++11 is to mark them `override`, or, if you prefer Qt macros and are using Qt 5, `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` (these do nothing on a C++98 compiler of course).

Answer (score 2):

Is your item located under a `QGraphicsItemGroup`?

I had this exact same issue until I found this quote:

"A `QGraphicsItemGroup` is a special type of compound item that treats itself and all its children as one item (i.e., all events and geometries for all children are merged together)."

(Look here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitemgroup.html)

What this means is that `QGraphicsItemGroup` calls `setHandlesChildEvents(true)`.

I fixed my issue by calling `parentItem->setHandlesChildEvents(false)` on any (and all) groups located above my item to capture hover events.  Poof!  The events began showing up in the virtual callbacks you mention.

Comment: I had this issue for a different problem, however it doesn't fix my problem that is similar to OP's

Comment: Fixed my issue, was not able to track back why items were not receiving the mouse hover events. Thanks!